# Can passengers flying into Thailand do the mandatory 14-day quarantine at home?

Tags: air-travel, thailand, covid-19

Can passengers flying into Thailand do the mandatory 14-day quarantine at home?

I read contradictory information in articles published today (2020-05-04) and yesterday on two well-known news websites:

https://thethaiger.com/coronavirus/cv19-asia/cv19-thailand/over-500-thais-fly-home-today-and-straight-into-quarantine ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200504151437/https://thethaiger.com/coronavirus/cv19-asia/cv19-thailand/over-500-thais-fly-home-today-and-straight-into-quarantine)):

> All returnees face a mandatory 14 day quarantine, either in their homes or at state-provided facilities, under strict guidelines

https://www.bangkokpost.com/thailand/general/1911652/new-quarantine-venues-for-returnees-in-bangkok ([mirror](https://archive.vn/3ZcCN)):

> Returnees are required to spend 14 days in state-designated quarantine facilities, many of them hotels, and must foot the bills themselves.

Comment: Question is, is this even relevant for "travel"? According to IATA the only flights allowed in are repatriation flights, and it apparently even spouses of Thai citizens cannot enter. I spoke to the spouse of a Thai, and according to their information you have to use a government-assigned facility; but it also seems there is little information to go around.

Comment: Two users flagged it as unfriendly or unkind and when I read it, I did feel it rather unkind. I did 'just delete it', not with a tag to it, but the system may have added it as it had been flagged that way. (It felt snarky, not thankful.) I was answering your question on Meta but you deleted it before I could post the answer. (Not see it as needed anymore.)

Comment: @averell See my reply on [Why was my comment simply thanking a commenter and quoting a definition deleted as not being nice?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6589/1810)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - just for the record, I did not see you answer before it was deleted, I did not flag it; and I see no reason to get into a meta discussion. My remark was rather rhetorical - your question seemed to assume that one can actually travel to Thailand, when this is not currently possible, except for repatriation of Thai citizens.

Comment: @averell no worries meta was for something else (comment deletion by a mod). Yes I'm asking for repatriated Thais and exceptions (e.g., diplomats).

Comment: @averell We have entertained questions on repatriation flights before. Personally, I don't think travel by expatriates or travel for other purposes than tourism ought to be off-topic but this question could even be relevant to a stranded Thai tourist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most currently non-Thai passengers flying into Thailand can't do the mandatory 14-day quarantine at home.

From https://mobile.twitter.com/RichardBarrow/status/1268924407537233920 ([mirror 1](https://web.archive.org/web/20200606035521/https://mobile.twitter.com/RichardBarrow/status/1268924407537233920), [mirror 2](https://archive.vn/wip/XmSVO)):

> Q2: If I fly to Thailand, can I quarantine in my own house or do state quarantine for free?
>
> A: No, for the foreseeable future, foreigners must book a stay in Alternative State Quarantine for 14-days at their own expense. These hotels will cost you between 32,000 and 60,000 Baht.

However, https://mobile.twitter.com/RichardBarrow/status/1282687924484497409 ([mirror](http://archive.is/esKrL)) and https://www.bangkokpost.com/thailand/general/1950708 ([mirror](https://archive.vn/oKSK4)) mention some exceptions:

> “Diplomat families are required to self-isolate at embassies or residences for 14 days and up until now there were no problems. The CCSA will rethink its measures to make them more comprehensive,” said Dr Taweesilp.

I don't know whether Thai passengers can quarantine at home. I  believe most, if not all, can't.