# Does the removal of German border control from 15th June apply to third-country nationals legally residing in these countries?

Tags: air-travel, germany, borders

It is announced that Germany will remove travel controls for entries from other EU countries, the Schengen-associated countries, Norway, Liechtenstein, Iceland and the UK on 15th June (https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/news/germany-to-lift-internal-border-controls-on-june-15-prolongs-those-with-austria-until-november-12/).

Is this based on your nationality or the country you are departing from?
For example, if you are a third-country national legally residing in one of these countries (as a long-term international student), would you be allowed into Germany from 15th of June or would you be subject to the easing of restrictions at a later date?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The imposed restrictions, with the exception of Spain, will **end** at 24:00h of the 15th of June 2020 (**not** 00:00h). This means that the normal travelling conditions for persons residing within the EU+ and the United Kingdom will be resumed as before. The same will apply for Spain on the 20th of June (I assume 00:00h).

As a holder of a valid **residence document** (permit or card) by 3rd Country Citizens the 90/180 rule will then again apply as before.

> This decision means that **travellers from other EU countries** will no longer need a valid reason for entering Germany. This also applies to entries from the Schengen associated countries, Norway, Liechtenstein and Iceland, as well as entries from the United Kingdom. For tourism and other travel, the information and warnings published by the Federal Foreign Office apply.

The goal is the full restoration of the freedom of movement again in Europe by July.

Nothing has yet changed for travel from **outside the Schengen Area**.

> The EU interior ministers want entry bans for travellers from third countries to be extended by an additional 14 days to 1 July. After this date, Seehofer said, there would be differentiated solutions depending on the countries’ epidemiological situations. He went on to say that the Commission would issue a recommendation on the matter next week.

See also [suggestions from the European Commission](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/157643/95267) made yesterday on this topic.

---

**Sources**:

- [BMI - Press - Checks at internal borders end on 15 June](https://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/pressemitteilungen/EN/2020/06/ende-binnengrenzkontrollen.html)
- [BMI - News - Federal Minister of the Interior: Full freedom of movement again in Europe from July](https://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/kurzmeldungen/EN/2020/06/uebergabe-staffelstab-eu-rp-en.html)

Comment: What does the 90/180 rule mean?

Comment: @Snow Short term visitors to Schengen without EU/EEA citizenship can usually only stay in the Schengen area for 90 days in any 180 day period. This also applies to non citizen residents/long term visa holders of a Schengen country, if they don't have EU citizenship they don't get freedom of movement throughout the area and have to follow the 90/180 rule in other Schengen countries.